# Counting the strictly increasing sequences

Tags: algorithm

I aligned the N candles from left to right. The ith candle from the left has the height Hi and the color Ci, an integer ranged from 1 to a given K, the number of colors.

Problem: , how many strictly increasing ( in height ) colorful subsequences are there? A subsequence is considered as colorful if every of the K colors appears at least one times in the subsequence.

```
For Ex: N=4 k= 3
      H   C
      1    1
      3    2  
      2    2
      4    3
```

only two valid subsequences are (1, 2, 4) and (1, 3, 4)

I think it is a problem of Fenwick Tree please provide me a approach how to proceeded with such type of problems

Comment: what are the constraints on N and K ?

Comment: Why is (1,2,3,4) not a valid subsequence? It is strictly increasing in height and includes each color at least once.

Comment: @Mshnik : H3 < H2 so (1,2,3,4) is not a strictly increasing sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a moment, let's forget about the colors. So the problem is simpler: count the number of increasing subsequences. This problem has a standard solution:
1. Map each value to `[0...n - 1]` range.
2. Let's assume the `f[value]` is the number of increasing subsequences that have `value` as their last element.
3. Initially, `f` is filled with 0.
4. After that, you iterate over all array elements from left to right and perform the following operation: `f[value] += 1 + get_sum(0, value - 1)`(it means that you add this element to all possible subsequences so that they remain strictly increasing), where `value` is the current element of the array and `get_sum(a, b)` returns the sum of `f[a] + f[a + 1] + ... + f[b]`.
5. The answer is `f[0] + f[1] + ... + f[n - 1]`.
Using binary index tree(aka Fenwick tree), it is possible to do `get_sum` operation in `O(log n)` and get `O(n log n)` total time complexity.

Now let's come back to the original problem. To take into account the colors, we can compute `f[value, mask]` instead of `f[value]`(that is, the number of increasing subsequences that have `value` as their last element and `mask`(it is a bitmask that shows which colors are present) colors). Then an update for each element looks like this:

```
for mask in [0...2^K - 1]:
     f[value, mask or 2^(color[i] - 1)] += 1 + get_sum(0, value - 1, mask)
```

The answer is `f[0, 2^K - 1] + f[1, 2^K - 1] + ... + f[n - 1, 2^K - 1]`.

You can maintain `2^K` binary index trees to achieve `O(n * log n * 2^K)` time complexity using the same idea as in a simpler problem.

Comment: when the first element of an array of Height k comes what does the get_sum(0,k-1) (as f[i] i<k should be 0) return since it is a first element please explain me about get_sum

Comment: would you explain be working of get_sum how it will be work that would clear everything

Comment: @user4213270 It is just one query to binary index tree.

Comment: mask or 2^(color[i] - 1) why or operator

Comment: @user4213270 The i-th element is added to the sequence, so its color should be added to the set of colors in the sequence.